# ASP.NET Web API return data every second

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

first of all I am sorry for my poor question title, but I can't think of everything better right now.

What I want to do seems quite simpel. I want my API to return, for example, a simple string every second for like 10 times.

Is there any way to achive this with ASP.NET?

And yes, obviously the actual usecase is different. My API is scraping some data and returning it after that. The problem is the scraping takes like 70 seconds. I would like it to return the data in smaller packages, so my application can start processing the data earlier.

But the way to achive this - if there is any - should be the same.
At least thats how I think of it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Think in terms of HTTP. Are you expecting to stream the response data for a single HTTP request, or are you expecting to make your first response finish quickly, and then make the client issue another request etc? Are you able to use web sockets instead?

Comment: While you could keep the request running for a longer period and send the response in chunks, ASP.NET API is not really made for that use-case. It might be better to initiate the scraping through an API call and to use SignalR for sending updates to the client or even initiate the scraping over SignalR altogether.

Comment: @JonSkeet I would like to perform only a single request. I would like to keep my client as "dumb" as possible...

Comment: @huysentruitw Would you be so king to explain this a little bit further? It seems interesting...

Comment: For ASP.NET Core, check [this post](https://medium.com/@chris.stephan1996/why-when-and-how-and-to-use-signalr-ef49b5b0dc11), for ASP.NET, check [this post](https://medium.com/@aparnagadgil/real-time-web-functionality-using-signalr-ba483efcb959). These are just some random posts, with a little bit of googling, you can find additional info around the SignalR topic. It's fairly easy to use, see SignalR as a full-duplex connection, where the server can call into client functions and the client can call into server methods.

Comment: I suspect a truly "dumb" client won't even want to start processing the response until it's complete. While this *may* be feasible, you need to expect it to be fiddly - and that proxies could easily mess things up for you too by adding buffering for example.

Comment: An example for chunked response can be found [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/getting-data-in-chunks-from-Asp-Net-server/), but I strongly advice against following this route.

Comment: Thanks you both :)

Comment: @huysentruitw well I fiddelt around with SignalR and eventrough not everything is working perfectly (the client for some reason waits until all data is transferred, before he processes it) and I'm still not shure if the error is in the Server or in the Client (and yes the Server is sending the data async), it definitly seems as a viable option and I'm confident to resolve this last error as well.

I would like to give you credit for pointing me in the right direction so could you please post an answer?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with http.

You must do long pooling on client side or you can create a socket connection between client and server. Package `signalr` is a great choice.